# Change CreationTime using the file name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell

I name all of my home video files according to an exact protocol.  An example is:   Aug 09,2005@13.21.12.mp4

Typically, the original file is not an mp4 so I go through the process of converting, which changes the Date Created property.  Although I can go in and change each one individually, I would like to use a batch file, either via a CMD prompt or powershell that extracts the date and time implied in the file name and changes the Date Created property.  I currently do this in two steps.

1. The CMD script here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946293/batch-set-date-time-attribute-according-to-the-names-of-the-files-in-a-folder only seems to change the Date Modified.
2. I use PowerShell to set the Date Created = to the Date Modified.  I would like to get rid of one of these steps.  All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Save this script as `Set-DateCreatedFromName.ps1`:

```
Param
(
    [string[]]$Path,
    [string]$Filter = '*.mp4',
    [switch]$Recurse
)

$Path | Get-ChildItem -Recurse:$Recurse -Filter $Filter | ForEach-Object {
    $DateTime = Get-Date
    $IsValidDate = [DateTime]::TryParseExact(
        $_.BaseName,
        # replace with 'MMM dd,yyyy@H.m.s' if using single digit for hours/minutes/seconds
        'MMM dd,yyyy@HH.mm.ss',
        [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
        [ref]$DateTime
    )
    if($IsValidDate){
        $_.CreationTime = $DateTime
    }
}
```

Run it from PowerShell like this:

```
& .\Set-DateCreatedFromName.ps1 -Path 'C:\MP4-1', 'D:\MP4-2' -Recurse -Filter '*.mp4'
```

Arguments:

- `-Path` - Required. Array of paths. E.g: `'C:\MP4-1', 'D:\MP4-2'`
- `-Recurse` - Optional. Recurse into subdirs, `false` if omitted.
- `-Filter` - Optional, `*.mp4` if omitted.